# In Popup editing, dropdownlist not working properly -Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am not able to View the DropDown in Popup ,but i can able to view in Inline.

Here is my code

```html
   

 columns.ForeignKey(o => o.BreakingNewsTypeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["BreakingNewsTypes"], "ID", "Description").Title("Type <!--<a href='javascript:onBreakingNewsTypes()'><span class='k-icon k-i-custom'></span></a>-->").EditorTemplateName("Alerts").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Type" }).Width(130);

.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
```

And Model for Dropdown  is Alerts.cshtm

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@using System.Collections

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                              .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["BreakingNewsTypes"])
                              //.OptionLabel("Select a value...")
                              .DataTextField("Description")
                              .DataValueField("ID")
                              .Events(e => e.Change("onBreakingTypeChange"))

)
```

Comment: Firstly, please check your browser developer console and see if the dropdown element is render in HTML or not. IMO Kendo dropdown behavior is different than the browser's native dropdown. Initially, they render as a span and upon click they change themselves to a drop menu. More or like this is a CSS issue to trying applying a border to render element and make them native dropdown look alike.

Comment: One more thing you have also mentioned it's in a popup thus there may be chance the popup is hiding your dropdown. If this is the case then dropdown z-index should be greater than your popup z-index. Native dropdown don't have any z-index but kendo dropdown do have. If these doesn't reflect any change then you need to submit more information.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Kindly help , how to change that Z-index value of dropdown/popup????

Comment: You will need to open developer console using inspect element and then navigate to the element id (in your case it's a dropdown) then locate the classes on right hand panel. In one of the wrapping div you will find certain class that uses a z-index. Increase it to either 9999 , 10000 or even more depending on your choice.